# Write Method provide Program

Tags: java

I am a beginner at java and for my class we are learning about methods. For my first program I have to write a method and provide a program for: double average(double x, double y, double z) returning the average of the arguments. Here is my program so far

```
//**METHOD**//

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter variable x");
    double x = in.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter variable y");
    double y = in.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter variable z");
    double z = in.nextDouble();

    double average;
    System.out.println("The average is: " + average);
```

//**TEST PROGRAM**//

```
    public static double average(double x, double y, double z)
    {
       double average = (x * y * z)/3;
       return average;
    }
```

Comment: What is your question? You should specify what you are having trouble with.

Comment: You want to add x, y, and z for an average - not multiply.

Answer (score 5):

A method is only useful if you use it. You will want to reference (or call) the method where you want to use it.

In your code:

```
System.out.println("The average is: " + average(x, y, z) );
```

And to clarify, the average is the sum of all values divided by the number of values.

In this case it would be `(x + y + z) / 3` not `(x * y * z) /3`

Answer (score 3):

```
double average = (x * y * z)/3;
//                  ^   ^ what?
```

Here's your first problem. Why are you multiplying?

```
double average;
System.out.println("The average is: " + average);
```

Your second problem is that you didn't actually call the method. If you just define a method and don't call it, Java doesn't know when you want it called or what arguments you want to use. Defining a variable with the same name doesn't implicitly call the method or anything like that. The method won't run at all. Call it with the arguments you want to get a value:

```
System.out.println("The average is: " + average(x, y, z));
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need your code to exist within a class and it will need a `public static void main(final String[] args) {}` method in order to run.

Answer (score 0):

Call the method like this:

```
double average = average(x, y, z);
System.out.println("The average is: " + average);
```

And for the record, the average is the sum of the terms divided by the number of terms, not the product. So change your average method to this:

```
public static double average(double x, double y, double z)
{
   double average = (x + y + z) / 3;
   return average;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, here is my new program

Now my program is telling me that there is an illegal start of the expression by the public static double average(double x, double y, double z) and I don't know why

Comment: @user3334727 I need to see all of your code to help you with that.